# Monaco editor not executing custom formatter. (version 0.33.0)

Tags: monaco-editor

I have made a example here

When I press right mouse click and then "Format Document", nothing happens.

I expected text to be changed to "test"

https://jsfiddle.net/y1v6hL4p/1/

```
require.config({ paths: { 'vs': 'https://unpkg.com/monaco-editor@0.8.3/min/vs' }});
window.MonacoEnvironment = { getWorkerUrl: () => proxy };

let proxy = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([`
    self.MonacoEnvironment = {
        baseUrl: 'https://unpkg.com/monaco-editor@0.33.0/min/'
    };
    importScripts('https://unpkg.com/monaco-editor@0.33.0/min/vs/base/worker/workerMain.js');
`], { type: 'text/javascript' }));

require(["vs/editor/editor.main"], function () {
    monaco.languages.registerDocumentFormattingEditProvider("html", {
            provideDocumentFormattingEdits(model, options) {
           
                return [
                    {
                        range: model.getFullModelRange(),
                        text: 'test',
                    },
                ];
            },
        });

    let editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('container'), {
        value: [
            '<Area>',
            '</Area>'
        ].join('\n'),
        language: 'html',
        theme: 'vs-dark'
    });
    
    editor.addListener('didType', () => {
        console.log(editor.getValue());
    });
});
```